# SMOTE resampling in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, resampling, imblearn

I used the `imblearn` library to do resampling on pandas dataframes.

I wanted to know if there was the same implementation for pyspark dataframes ?

For instance I tried to use the code proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53936850/oversampling-or-smote-in-pyspark/57483738#57483738) but I had multiple errors by using the code as is.

Thank you for your help !